# Reduce Partitions by COALESCE in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I run Spark SQL queries and use them to perform data transformations and then store the final result-set (after a series of transformation steps) to `S3`.

I recently noticed that one of my jobs was creating a large number of partition files while writing to `S3`and taking a long time to complete (in fact it was failing). So I want to know if there is any way to do a `COALESCE` like function in the SQL API to reduce the number of partitions before writing to `S3` ?

I know that the SQL API equivalent of re-partition is `Cluster By`. So was wondering if there is anything similar for `COALESCE` operation as well in the SQL API too.

Please note that I only have access to the SQL API so my question strictly pertains to Spark **SQL** API only. (For e.g. `SELECT col from TABLE1 WHERE` ...)

We use Spark SQL 2.4.6.7

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-hints.html) suggest using hints to coalesce partitions, e.g.

```sql
SELECT /*+ COALESCE(3) */ col from TABLE1
```

Comment: Thanks. I see this is for Spark v3.0. Does this work for Spark 2.4 as well ?

Comment: Found it. It supports 2.4. Mare information here : https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-hint-framework.html